# 急{きゅう}に vs.すぐに – usage in context

Tags: word-choice, words, usage

In 合格できる N3 (page 28), I found the following exercise:

> うちの子{こ}は新{あた}しいおもちゃ見{み}ると、(　　　　)ほしがる。
>
> 1.　急に　　　2.　じっと　　　3.すぐに　　　4.しっかり

I have to fill in with the correct word. I think it's either 1 or 3, but I don't know the difference between those two. I think that to some extent both 急に and すぐに can be understood as *immediately*.

In this context, which is the most appropriate word and why?

Comment: If it were 〜欲しくなる instead if 欲しがる, somehow 急に 'feels' right, but I can't quite explain why. Perhaps I've heard the whole phrase 急に欲しくなる several times...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`急に` is like `suddenly` I think, this word includes the meanings of  *without notice* or *unexpected*.

`すぐに` is immediately, as you mentioned.

The context describes the baby's general habit, so must be *expected* things. the answer is 3.`すぐに`.